# How to install Micromax 355G USB wireless modem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, usb, usb-modem, usb-modeswitch

How do I install a Micromax MMX 355G Data Card USB modem? I tried lsusb and sudo wvdialconf /etc/wvdial.conf, but neither of these commands detected my USB modem. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I'm newbie to ubuntu please help

```
krish@krish-Inspiron-5521:~$ sudo wvdialconf /etc/wvdial.conf
Editing `/etc/wvdial.conf'.

Scanning your serial ports for a modem.

Modem Port Scan<*1>: S0   S1   S2   S3   S4   S5   S6   S7   
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S8   S9   S10  S11  S12  S13  S14  S15  
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S16  S17  S18  S19  S20  S21  S22  S23  
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S24  S25  S26  S27  S28  S29  S30  S31  


Sorry, no modem was detected!  Is it in use by another program?
Did you configure it properly with setserial?
```

how I would proceed. please help this newbie I don't want to switch windows again for this silly problem.